# I accidently deleteed all java files from centos machine

Tags: java, linux, centos

I accidently deleted all java files from centos 8 VM.
Now I am trying to install java `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y` but after installation I am unable to see java version.

```
java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

Could you please help here.

Comment: `rpm -q  java-1.8.0-openjdk` - see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-determining-finding-path-that-yum-package-installed-to/

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

`rpm -q  java-1.8.0`
if it displays the java, then fine or else go for step 2

Step 2:

`$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`